# How to pass a list of objects to a [HTTPPost]controller parameter, in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, submit, http-post, asp.net-mvc-controller

i have the next view:

```
@model IEnumerable<L5ERP.Model.BLL.BusinessObjects.MTR_MonthlyTransfer>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExpenseMonthlyTransferProcessing", "BudgetTransfer", Model.ToList())){
<table class ="divTable">
<tr>
    <th>Transferir</th>

    <th>
       Clave
    </th>

    <th>
        Monto
    </th>

</tr> 
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.MTR_Bool, new { @class = "checkMTR", @checked = "checked" })

    </td>
    <td>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.MTR_Key, new {@class = "longInput" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @String.Format("{0:F}", item.MTR_Amount)
    </td>
</tr>   
 } 
</table> 
}
```

and my controller like this

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExpenseMonthlyTransferProcessing(List<MTR_MonthlyTransfer> lstMtr)
    { return View(lstMTR); }
```

But when i do the post my list is null, how can i send my list through the submit button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `@model` to an array (`L5ERP.Model.BLL.BusinessObjects.MTR_MonthlyTransfer[]`) or something else that implements `IList<>`:

```
@model L5ERP.Model.BLL.BusinessObjects.MTR_MonthlyTransfer[]

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Length; i ++) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model[i].MTR_Bool, new { @class = "checkMTR", @checked = "checked" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model[i].MTR_Key, new {@class = "longInput" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @String.Format("{0:F}", item.MTR_Amount)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Ed is referring to the fact that you need to index the names for the modelbinder. when his example renders the MTR_Key textbox would look like <input type="text" name="MTRMonthlyTransfer[0].MTR_Key" ... /> This enables the modelbinder to know which element in the array each input belongs to. Alternately, submitting it as an array of json objects should work.

Answer (score 0):

receive a FormCollection and parse the items in it manually

Use F12 to check the post in your navigator to see if it are sending the content you expected.

Comment: I fill my table with a FOR instead a FOREACH

but my i use a .ToList in mi Model, now doing this i can access to de indexs of my collection.

here's the code of my view:

<table class ="divTable">
<tr>
    <th>Transferir</th>

    <th>
       Clave
    </th>

    <th>
        Monto
    </th>

</tr>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ToList().Count; i++){ 
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.ToList()[i].MTR_Key)
    </td>
 </tr>}

This works ;) !